# Assigning a populated matrix to an unpopulated matrix

Tags: r

I have a `data frame` which I construct as follows:

```
m <- matrix("matrix", nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
dm <- data.frame(m)
```

My understanding is that this will make `dm` a data frame with 2 columns and 2 rows, each element of which will be a matrix.  My problem is that I have a method that returns a matrix that contains a bunch of numbers, but when I try to assign this matrix to one of the "empty" matrices in `dm`:

dm[1, 1] <- GetPopulatedMatrix()

I get the following error:

`replacement has 873 rows, data has 1`

I'm assuming that this is because the matrix I'm trying to assign to isn't the same size as the matrix that is returned by `GetPopulatedMatrix`, but I'm not sure how to initialize `dm` with 4 matrices (assuming a 2x2 `data frame`) of the correct size.  Assume that I will know ahead of time the exact dimensions of the matrix being returned by `GetPopulatedMatrix`.  Any ideas how I can initialize `dm` so that I'll later be able to assign a populated matrix to its elements?

I know how to initialize a `matrix` with a specified number of columns and rows, I just don't know how to do it when the matrices are elements of a `data frame` or other collection.

Thanks in advance!  I'm new to R, so I'm sure this is a dumb question, but this is my last resort before I'm forced to destroy my computer in frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption about the content of `dm` is wrong. Your matrix `m` is a 2x2 matrix with each cell containing the string "matrix". `dm` has the same content but is a `data.frame`.

When each call to `GetPopulatedMatrix()` returns a matrix but you don't know the dimensions of these matrixes upfront, I would recommend you to save your results in a list.

```
results <- list()
results[[1]] <- GetPopulatedMatrix()
results[[2]] <- GetPopulatedMatrix()
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  So is it not possible to store a matrix in each cell of a `data.frame`, then?

Comment: No. Each cell of a `data.frame` can contain 1 single value (numeric/character/logical) but not many (matrix, lists, other data.frames). But of course you can create a 100x100 matrix and assign 100 matrixes of size 10x10 to it (next to / below each other).